# Scroll direction in an OnPageChangeListener

Tags: android

Is it possible to know the direction of the scroll in the method `onPageScrolled` of the `OnPageChangeListener` applied to a `ViewPager`?

Comment: you can easily get the position of the page.. with the position increasing you can determine it as  swiping towards right end pages.. with the position decreasing it is swiping towards left end pages

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've used something like this:

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    int oldPos = mPager.getCurrentItem();

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {

            if(position > oldPos) {
                 //Moving to the right

            } else if(position < oldPos) {
                 //Moving to the Left
            }

        .
        .
        .
```

--Edit--

Sorry, changed to onPageScrolled, not onPageSelected..

Comment: Can you explain the change? It works for me in onPageSelected but onPageScrolled

Comment: Using your code above, it works for me in onPageSelected, but not in onPageScrolled. onPageScrolled always hits the else case

Comment: Without seeing your particular implementation, there's nothing to say. Maybe post a question, with your code and explaining the issue, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Your edit says you changed it from onPageScrolled from onPageSelected. I was just wondering if you could explain why you did that.

Comment: Because OP asked about onPageScrolled, but initially I thought he/she was asking about onPageSelected..

Comment: This worked for me, _HOWEVER_ I needed to keep the **`int oldPos = mPager.getCurrentItem();`** in the **`onPageScrolled`** and, as suggested, add the **`if`** clause to the **`onPageScrolled`** portion.

Comment: @CACuzcatlan late response sorry, but maybe it will be useful to someone else. I found that **`onPageScrolled`** is called every time the Pager view is dragged one px in either direction (possibly dp?), so in one drag it will be called many times until the user lets go of the Pager view. **`onPageSelected`** is called right before page change when the page starts settling in its new position. The two events seem to be mutually exclusive in time, meaning that there is no temporal overlap between the time windows when each event is triggered.